# Sphinx - searching again

Tags: php, postgresql, sphinx

I got weird issues with Sphinx. In some cases Sphinx don't finding rows in index (and I'm pretty sure that they are there).

Below my index and source config:

```
source pl_PL_search_queries {
    type = pgsql
    sql_host = XXX
    sql_user = XXX
    sql_pass = XXX
    sql_db = XXX
    sql_port = XXX
    sql_query = select id, title, slug FROM searcher.query ORDER BY results_count
    sql_field_string = title
    sql_attr_string = slug
}

index pl_PL_search_queries {
    source = pl_PL_search_queries
    path = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/pl_PL/pl_PL_search_queries
    min_word_len = 2
    min_prefix_len = 1
    expand_keywords = 0
    infix_fields = title
    charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, a..z, U+0143->U+0144, \
                    U+0104->U+0105, U+0106->U+0107, U+0118->U+0119, \
                    U+0141->U+0142, U+00D3->U+00F3, U+015A->U+015B, \
                    U+0179->U+017A, U+017B->U+017C, U+0105, U+0107, \
                    U+0119, U+0142, U+00F3, U+015B, U+017A, U+017C, \
                    U+0144
    wordforms = /usr/local/sphinx/wordform-pl-dict-urf-8
}
```

And example cases:

**Case 1:**

Search for **d610**

```
$objSearch->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
$objSearch->SetRankingMode(SPH_RANK_NONE);
$objSearch->setSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "@relevance DESC");
$arrResult = $objSearch->query('*d610*', $strIndex);
```

Any rows found.

```
select count(1) from searcher.query where slug like '%d610%';
```

42 rows found..

**Case 2:**

Search for **nicon**

```
$objSearch->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
$objSearch->SetRankingMode(SPH_RANK_NONE);
$objSearch->setSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "@relevance DESC");
$arrResult = $objSearch->query('*nikon*', $strIndex);
```

Found 7 rows

```
select count(1) from searcher.query where slug like '%nicon%';
```

15 rows found

---

My target here is to get results matches by language (fulltext with wordforms file) AND matches fits by sql's LIKE '%XXX%' (normal fit, not full text) and order it by @relevance

How to achieve that and why that codes don't work ?

Comment: you have used 'min_prefix_len' which enables prefix matches only. But querying with two stars, which needs 'min_infix_len'

Comment: So, you suggest to set min_infix_len to 1 ?

Comment: Well to run queries like `*d610*` will need it set to something (between 1 and 4 :)

Comment: Looks great! In this case I had to comment out min_prefix_len (its not allowed to use min_prefix_len and min_infix_len as both, and its logic) :) 
But what I see - allow sphinx to search by wildacrds (by enabling min_infix_len) is disabling fulltext searching (i mean for phrase "books" finding results for "books" and "book"), is it true ? If yes - I should to make 2 indexes (one for fulltext, second for wildcard searching), make two searches and merge results, right ?

Comment: No. Shouldnt be related. But to get books and book to match together, need to enable `morphology` - eg with `stem_en`. Should be able to use min_infix_len and morphology on the same index! There isn't a built in PL stemmer, so might need to use libstemmer.